# Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: winforms, interop

I'm getting this error when I'm using COM reference in winform. I tried using Window Media Player COM in winform and it's working fine. But I got this error when I tried using with other COM dll.

I tried "regsvr32" to that COM dll but it was successfully registered but I'm still getting this error when I run my winform that is using that COM object.

Comment: Changing the target platform to x86 in Mark's deleted answer helps.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are missing the Office Web Components 2003.

OWC installer can be downloaded here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=22276